# MARC21 - bibliographic record file: script to create new fields and put there modified values

Tags: solr, marc

I have a MARC-file with bibliographic records which consist of different fields that have values. e.g. Author, Title, Publication year etc. The data structure looks like this:

```
700  1   |a King, Robert Harlen 
852  L   |3 81TYD2565(2) 
852  L   |3 Ugk25 1:2B
```

To implement a certain feature I need e.g. the value of field 852|3 copied, modified and written in the record-file like this:

```
852  L   |4 TYD
852  L   |4 Ugk25
```

As I am new to this I would like to know if someone has an idea what would be the best approach to do that?

ps: the MARC-file will be indexed into a SolR-index. Is there a possibility to make the changes during the indexing?

Answer (score 0):

There are a good number of [packages to work with MARC](http://wiki.code4lib.org/index.php/Working_with_MARC) for a variety of programming languages. If you're going to be indexing MARC data into Solr, you should look at [SolrMarc](https://code.google.com/p/solrmarc/). It could be possible to do this during the indexing process if you don't need to persist the changes back into the MARC record - SolrMarc allows for custom indexing scripts written in either Java or BeanShell.